# Use Express.js endpoints with promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to use express with promises but I can't make it work.
when I uncomment `(1)` I can set response as 200, but whatever I try to set as response in promise `(2,3,4)` It always returns `401`

I can `console.log` `data` in `then` so promise is surely resolving but I believe that `401` is send because function doesn't wait for promise to be resolved is that right?

What I'm doing wrong and how I can set response from promise?

Thanks in advance!

```
app.get('/get_data', function (req, res) {

  //res.json(200, {}); return; --> (1) gives expected 200 

  tree.getData(req.param('ids'))
     .then(function (data) { 
         // console.log('data'); --> (2) logs requested array of data
         //return res.json(200,{}); --> (3) gives 401
         return res.send(data); // --> (4) gives 401
     }).fail(function (err) {
         // never goes here
         console.log(err);
         return res.json(550, err);
     });
});
```

Comment: should it be `.catch` instead of `.fail`?

Comment: are you wanting a `401` to invoke the `.fail` method?

Comment: @JoshC. I want to be able to send any response from `then` method but for now I can't even though I set `200` in `then` it ignores it (and it goes to `then`)

Comment: @JoshC. is correct. If you are using "native" `Promise`s, there is no `fail()`, only [`catch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add a return before `tree.getData` to return the promise and its result. An A+ Promise has `catch()` not `fail()`

Also when setting a status code in Express you need to use `res.status().send()` not `res.send(status, data)` [Express `res.send()` Docs](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.send)

```
app.get('/get_data', function (req, res) {

  return tree.getData(req.param('ids'))
     .then(function (data) { 
         return res.status(200).send(data)
     }).catch(function (err) {
         // never goes here
         console.log(err);
         return res.status(550).json(err);
     });
});
```